# Subtraction from new results

Tags: r, subtraction

I have been searching for a while now for the solution to this but I can't seem to find it.

For example : 
I have one value : `x = 22000` 
I have one column with values `Dataframe$netto_weights` e.g.: `1000, 2000, 5000,1000..`

I am looking for a way to subtract these `netto_weights` and save the results from each deduction of `X`.

I've tried combining `sapply` with `lead` or `lag` functions but I keep getting different results.

The output would be something like:
`x = 22000`

```
1.  21000 (22000-1000)
2.  19000 (21000-2000)
3.  14000 (19000-5000)
4.  13000 (14000-1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
x <- 22000
vec <- c(1000, 2000, 5000, 1000)

x - cumsum(vec)

[1] 21000 19000 14000 13000
```